# Changing siteurl breaks site

Tags: site-url

I am hosting my site on amazon ec2. I have purchased a domain name via godaddy and have forwarded it to the IP address of my amazon instance. I forwarded with masking turned on so that users do not see the IP in the address bar. It works fine, when I go to mysite.com the content loads.

I now need to change the wordpress address and the site address to `mysite.com` since they are defaulting to the ip address and i want to use permalinks for the rest of the site. When I do this the site no longer works. Site won't load and I can't access admin.

If I change just the wordpress address to mysite.com and leave the site address as the IP I am given an admin login page with broken css but when I try to use it nothing happens.

I have attempted to change the urls via the admin interface, directly in the database (updating siteurl & home in the `wp_options` table) and via the `wp-config.php`. all methods produce the same result.

I see lots of questions posted that are *similar* to this but seem to find solutions that don't work for me.

Any ideas on what I might be missing here?? I'm kind of running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your theme template functions.php

```
update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );
```

Comment: sadly, this does not work either. it seems to have the same effect as the other two options, it updates siteurl & home in the wp_options database table and that then breaks the site.